# React-Native | Unhandle promise JSON Parse error

Tags: node.js, api, react-native, authentication

I try to create a simple login/signup sistem using `react-native` and some api wrote in `nodejs`. For the authentication system I'm using the `jwt`.

This is the code of my login API:

```
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  const { error } = loginValidation(req.body);
  if ( error ) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

  //Checking if the mail exists
  const user = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email});
  if ( !user ) return res.status(400).send('Email not found');

  //Password is correct
  const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
  if ( !validPassword ) return res.status(400).send('Invalid password');
  
  //Create and assign the JWT
  const token = jwt.sign({_id: user._id}, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET);
  res.header('auth-token', token).send(token);
});
```

And this is the code for the login form wrote in react-native:

```
<View style={{flex: 4, justifyContent: 'center', width: '100%'}}>
  <View style={{height: '70%', width: '100%'}}>
    <Text style={styles.question}>
      ACCEDI
    </Text>
    <View style={{width: '100%', paddingTop: '5%', paddingHorizontal: '10%'}}>
      <Form
        ref='form'
        options={options}
        type={User}
        value={this.state.value}
        onChange={this._onChange}
      />
    </View>
    <View style={{width: '100%', flexDirection:'row', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <View style={{width: '10%'}}></View>
      <View style={{width: '70%'}}>  
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonpassword} onPress={ () => this.props.navigation.navigate('pippo') }>  
          <Text style={styles.signup}>
            Hai dimenticato la password?
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>  
    </View>
    <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <View style={{height: 50, width: 150, alignItems: 'center', paddingTop: '2%'}}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={this._handleAdd}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  </View>
</View>
```

When the `login button` is clicked the function `_handleAdd` is called. That function contains this code:

```
_handleAdd = () => {
    const value = this.refs.form.getValue();
    console.log(value);
    if ( value ) {
      const data = {
        email: value.username,
        password: value.password
      }
      fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/user/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        cache: 'no-cache',
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        }
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((body) => {
        console.log(body);
        alert(data);
      });
    }
    else {
      alert('All filds are require');
    }
  }
```

The prolem is when the button is clicked. I have this error:

> [Unhandled promise rejection: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9"]
>
> - node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:37:14 in tryCallOne
> - node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:123:25 in
> - ... 8 more stack frames from framework internals

## EDIT

The `console.log(response)` return this:

```
Response {
  "_bodyBlob": Blob {
    "_data": Object {
      "blobId": "1311DDB1-F839-403E-9FEF-E7D3072F9AA1",
      "name": "login.html",
      "offset": 0,
      "size": 149,
      "type": "text/html",
    },
  },
  "_bodyInit": Blob {
    "_data": Object {
      "blobId": "1311DDB1-F839-403E-9FEF-E7D3072F9AA1",
      "name": "login.html",
      "offset": 0,
      "size": 149,
      "type": "text/html",
    },
  },
  "headers": Headers {
    "map": Object {
      "auth-token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1ZDhmN2UyNjdlZTIwNTI5ZDI1YjUzM2IiLCJpYXQiOjE1Njk2OTAxOTV9.K_sCEXG2obYE2y-wbX02Tqq_yG8rsOCZKr1YyZlurMQ",
      "connection": "keep-alive",
      "content-length": "149",
      "content-type": "text/html; charset=utf-8",
      "date": "Sat, 28 Sep 2019 17:03:15 GMT",
      "etag": "W/\"95-Gmy4omr48TDbf5eqm/r1yJHUQRg\"",
      "x-powered-by": "Express",
    },
  },
  "ok": true,
  "status": 200,
  "statusText": undefined,
  "type": "default",
  "url": "http://localhost:3000/api/user/login",
}
```

Comment: What's the response look like?

Comment: @DaveNewton I don't understand what you mean

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

> res.header('auth-token', token).send(token);

You are basically sending the token back as is, not as json.
Yet in your front end code you're expecting json.

Try doing this:

```
res.header('auth-token', token).send({token: token});
```

Comment: No, the problem persists

Comment: try doing the same with all the data you're sending back:
eg: res.status(400).send({message: 'Email not found'})
the message you're getting implies that the response from the API isn't valid json. try also putting a console.log(response) before returning the response.json()

Comment: I just edit my question with the result of the `console.log(response)`

Answer (score 0):

In the back-end, use [`res.json`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.json) instead of `res.send`: it'll force the payload to be `JSON.stringify`ed and the `Content-Type` accordingly. That or manually jsonify the token: `res.send(JSON.stringify(token))`.

As [pointed out earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58148306) your problem is that your front-end expects JSON, but your server sends plain data: your token, with `JSON.stringify` applied on it, will be encapsulated in double quotes, making it readable as JSON on the other side.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your code as

```
.then((response) => response.text())
.then((res) => {console.log("res is",res);}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change `return response.json()` to `response` and remove `console.log()`s.

Comment: Could you please provide a piece of code as an example?